# Why does ASP.NET Core 5 Web API prevent HttpPost request access?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I have configured a `Configure` method in my `Startup.cs` file like this:

```
app.UseCors(option => option
                         .AllowAnyOrigin()
                         .AllowAnyHeader()
                         .AllowAnyMethod() );
```

But when publishing a project and uploading files to Plesk, the `HttpPost` method won't work at all, and I get this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: the same origin policy disallows reading the remote resource (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500.

I have been set `AllowAnyHeader()` previously but it seems it commands does not work. Why - and how can I fix this?

**Edit:**

I have these snipped in the Web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <remove verb="OPTIONS" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

But whole of [site](http://www.dastshafa.ir) wont run.

**Edit:**

I have used these snipped in the Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers(); 
            services.AddControllers()
             .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions
                 .ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddCors(opt => opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
            {
                c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using a wrong syntax, try this

```
services.AddCors(opt =>  opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", c =>
            { 
                c.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            }));
 ....

 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it wont work

Comment: @albert You have to post your startup  ,  because this code should be in the special places. I would like to see where you put it.

Comment: Please check out the last edit.

Comment: @albert  I see AddControllers are doubled. IMHO you have to remove the first one.

Comment: Oh yeah agree with you thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> when publishing a project and uploading files to Plesk, the HttpPost method won't work at all

If the request exceed the `maxAllowedContentLength` limitation, which would cause the issue even though we have enabled CORS.

Please check if the issue happens while the browser client upload large file(s). And you can try to increase the value of `maxAllowedContentLength` on your web server based on your actual scenario then check if it can help fix the issue.

```
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="90000000" />
</requestFiltering>
```

Comment: I have edited post above please check it. tnx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/serge) .

According to Serge helps ,services.AddControllers() are duplicated .
I remove one of them and project works properly.